# How can I make a choce between my tasks in airflow?

Tags: python, sql, airflow

I have a table in my DB where I'm logging some statuses.
If the status is ok for some date I should run sending_reports_if_success task, if it's not ok then sending_reports_if_failed.

How can I create a making choice task which will get result from
sql :

```
select count(*) from r_summary rs
where rs.status = 'Not Ok'
and rs.created_date = '{start_task_time}';
```

And if count = 1 then I should run failure task, if count = 0 then sucess task

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 3):

`BranchPythonOperator` is suitable for you case. You can pass the result from your query task to branching task and it will direct the flow to correspondingly using task ID.

```
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator


def choose_branch(query_result):
    if query_result == 1:
        return "sending_reports_if_success_task_id"

    return "sending_reports_if_failed_task_id"

branching = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='choose_report_branch',
    python_callable=choose_branch,
    op_args=["{{ ti.xcom_pull('your_query_task', 'your_return_key') }}"]
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can write a task that will return a key?
`def extract_data(conn_id, **context):
    engine = get_conn(conn_id)
    df = pd.read_sql_query(f'''select * from r_summary rs where rs.status = 'OK' and rs.created_date = '{start_task_time}'::timestamp with time zone;''',con=engine)
    return df

checking_exists_reports = PythonOperator(
  task_id='checking_exists_reports',
  python_callable=extract_data,
  op_kwargs={
  'load_date': '{{ts}}',
  'conn_id' : 'postrgres'
  }
 )`

Comment: you can use `context["task_instance"].xcom_push(key="your_query_task", value="your_value")` in `extract_data` function to push desired value to xcom under `your_query_task` key.